# Advantage storing big logs in MongoDB or Hadoop for analytics vs. Zip files on filer?

Tags: mongodb, logging, hadoop, analytics

At the moment, we store a huge amount of logs (30G/Day x3 Machines = av. 100G) of a filer. Logs are zipped.

The actual tool to search that logs, is searching the corresponding logs (according to timerange), copying them localy, unzip them, and search the xml for information and display.

We are studying the possibility to make a spunk-like tool to search that logs (it is the output of the message bus : xml-messages sent to other systems).

What are the advantage to rely on a mongo-like db, instead of querying the zipped logfile directly ?
We could also index some data in a db, and let the program search on targeted zip files...
What brings a mongodb... or hadoop more ?

Comment: Why do you presume that there are only advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on MongoDB and currently working on Hadoop so I can list some differences that you might find interesting.

1. MongoDB will need you to store your files as documents (instead of raw text data). HDFS can store it as files and allow you to use custom MapReduce programs to process them.
2. MongoDB will require you to choose a good sharding key in order to efficiently distribute the load across the cluster. Since you are storing log files it might be difficult.
3. If you can store the logs formatted into documents in MongoDB it will allow you query the data with very low latency across huge amounts of logs. My last project had inbuilt logging based on MongoDB and analysis is extremely fast as compared to MapReduce analysis of raw text logs. But the logging has to be done from ground up.
4. In Hadoop you have technologies like Hive, HBase and Impala which will help you analyze the text format logs, but the latency of MapReduce needs to be kept in mind (there are ways to optimize the latency in though).

To summarize: If you can implement mongoDB based logging in the entire stack go for MongoDB but if you already have text format logs then go for Hadoop. If you can convert your XML data into MongoDB documents in realtime then you can get a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge of Hadoop is limited, so I will focus on MongoDB.

You could store each log entry in MongoDB. When you create an index on the time field, you can easily get a specific time range. [MongoDB will have support for full text search in version 2.4](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/40513621310/mongodb-text-search-experimental-feature-in-mongodb) which would certainly be an interesting feature for your use-case, but it isn't production-ready yet. Until then, searching for substrings is a very slow operation. So you would have to convert the XML trees which are relevant for your searches to mongodb objects and create indices for the most searched fields.

But you should be aware that storing your logs in MongoDB will mean that **you will need a lot more hard drive space**. MongoDB does not compress the payload data and also adds some own meta-data overhead, so it will require even more disk space than the unzipped logs. Also, when you use the new text search feature, it will take even more disk space. During a presentation I saw, the text index was two times as large as the data it was indexing. Sure, this feature is still work in progress, but I wouldn't bet on it becomming a lot less in the final version.

Comment: So there are no advantage ?

Comment: That depends on if you have time to wait for 2.4 and how easy it is for you to get more disk space.

Comment: Lets say I have time to wait and diskspace, what would be the advantage of mongoDB, in comparison to indexing zip files in a ownmade db to search with a selfmade tool with fulltext on selected zip files ?

Comment: you wouldn't have to develop an ownmade tool to replicate all of MongoDBs features? Given unlimited time and resources you could of course produce an inhouse solution which is perfectly tailored to you use-case and better than any off-the-shelf solution in every regard. But do you *have* unlimited time and resources?